# Setting up Python on Visual Studio Code on WIN10

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use openCV to do a small color detection from a camera. I followed and used [this youtube code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cMJwqxskyek&list=WL&index=63&t=12s&ab_channel=CreepyD) and downloaded openCV. I also downloaded the Python and Code Runner extension through Visual Studio Code.

I keep getting an error that **python is not installed**.

What am I doing wrong here as I am using the same code from the video found from his github

ERROR MESSAGE IN TERMINAL:

```
[Running] python -u "C:\Users\LINEA~1.LAP\AppData\Local\Temp\tempCodeRunnerFile.python"
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
[Done] exited with code=9009 in 2.123 seconds
```

https://github.com/CreepyD246/Simple-Color-Detection-with-Python-OpenCV

Comment: if python wasn't even found, this can't possibly be an opencv issue because you need python first.

Answer (score 0):

This error is occurring because while you have the Python extension for VSC installed, you don't have the Python interpreter installed, which is a separate piece of software. You can find the Python installer [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/). I recommend adding Python to PATH (an option it gives during the installation).

Once you've got Python installed, you'll still need to install Python bindings for OpenCV. This can be done from the terminal, by typing `pip install opencv-python`. If this doesn't work, try `py -m pip install opencv-python`.

Comment: Thank you so much! but now I have another problem, the code seems like its trying to run normal, but I get this error, do you think I have a problem with how I set the path in the environment variables?

Comment: [Running] python -u "c:\Users\linea.LAPTOPI7-DANIEL\Downloads\TEST OPENCV.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\linea.LAPTOPI7-DANIEL\Downloads\TEST OPENCV.py", line 11, in <module>
    webcam_video = opencv.VideoCapture(0)
AttributeError: module 'opencv' has no attribute 'VideoCapture'

[Done] exited with code=1 in 1.648 seconds

Comment: It seems like opencv's python binding uses cv2, have you tried importing that instead?